# What happens to a service running with a user account password got changed?

Tags: service, user-accounts

E.g.

I am running a windows Service configured to run under a user account I have changed the password for the user account.

What happens to the Service, if i am not changing the log on password for the user account on that service?

I wanted to know whether the Windows will retry to log in using the old credentials and get the account locked?

How many retires it would do?

Answer (score 2):

The service will keep running. But it won't start the next time. You will have to reconfigure the service with the new password.